# Why are all my values being updated in my json file?

Tags: python, json, kivy

I have a list of buttons that when pressed, add a value of 1 to `score`. The button is considered a child of `screen_two.ids.streak_zone`. When I press the button it updates the value of `score` for all the buttons in the json file. How do I make it only update one button?

Heres my code:

```
def add_score(self, obj):
        for child in reversed(self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.children):
            name = child.text

            with open("streak.json", "r") as file:
                read = json.load(file)

            for key in read.keys():
                if key == name:
                    with open("streak.json", "r+") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)
                        data[key]['score']+=1
                        f.seek(0)
                        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
                        f.truncate()
```

json file:

```
{
    "one": {
        "action": "one",
        "delay": 1558824388.0762293,
        "seconds": 60,
        "score": 5,
        "delta": 1558224388.0762293
    },
    "two": {
        "action": "two",
        "delay": 1558824393.8408294,
        "seconds": 60,
        "score": 5,
        "delta": 1558224393.8408294
    }
}
```

Comment: you run `for child` loop so you do it for all buttons. Maybe add `print()` in some places to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed.

Comment: I don't know why do you load the same data second time if you already have it in variable `read`. Instead of `for key` loop you can check onlu `if name in read.keys():` and then change value  in `read[name]["score"]` and then open file to write all data again.

Comment: I'm not sure but you should check `obj` - maybe you have clicked button in `obj` and you don't have to use `for child` loop which runs your code for all children.

Comment: thanks removing the child loop worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed child loop and made `name = obj.text`

code:

```
    def add_score(self, obj):
        name = obj.text

        with open("streak.json", "r") as file:
            read = json.load(file)

        for key in read.keys():
            if key == name:
                with open("streak.json", "r+") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                    data[key]['score']+=1
                    f.seek(0)
                    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
                    f.truncate()
```